# I am facing problems while adding foreign key in heidisql

Tags: foreign-keys, heidisql

I am trying to add a foreign key to a table in heidisql. 
When I open the foreign key tab, the "add" button does not work.
Is there anybody who can help me with the solution?
Thank you.

I have changed the engine to "InnoDB" as suggested in other answers.

[notice the "add" button in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI88l.png)

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are supported only by a few table engines, for example InnoDB. I assume that specific table has some other engine, probably MyISAM. You can see the engine of the table in the *Options* tab:

[image]